# Python3: Dynamically invoking a method with dictionary of parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to be able to dynamically invoke a method on a class that accepts various parameters based on the string name and a dictionary of variables.  I know how to find the signature with the inspect module, and I can get the method with the getattr, but I do not know how to assign the parameters in the correct order to invoke it in a purely dynamic way.

```
class MyClass():
    def call_me(a, b, *args, foo='bar', **kwargs):
        print('Hey, I got called!')

command = {
          'action':'call_me',
          'parameters':{
                        'a': 'Apple',
                        'b': 'Banana',
                        'args':['one','two','three','four'],
                        'foo':'spam',
                        'clowns':'bad',
                        'chickens':'good'
                       }
           }

me = MyClass()
action = getattr(me,command['action'])

... now what?
```

I need to be able to dynamically call this function as if this code were used, without any foreknowledge of the actual parameters for the method:

```
a = command['parameters']['a']
b = command['parameters']['b']
args = command['parameters']['args']
foo = command['parameters']['foo']
kwargs = {
          'clowns': command['parameters']['clowns'],
          'chickens':command['parameters']['chickens']
         }

value = action(a, b, *args, foo=foo, **kwargs)
```

Surely there is a good pythonic way to do this.

**Edit**:  Fixed getattr to call instance of MyClass instead of MyClass directly.

Comment: `action(**command['parameters'])`

Comment: @falsetru It's not that easy because of `*args`.

Comment: `args=command['parameters'].pop('args', None); action(**command['parameters'], *args)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best way I have found so far to capture every possible combination of normal args, *args, keyword args and **kwargs without getting any errors:

```
import inspect
class MyClass():
    def a(self):
        pass
    def b(self,foo):
        pass
    def c(self,foo,*extras):
        pass
    def d(self,foo,food='spam'):
        pass
    def e(self,foo,**kwargs):
        pass
    def f(self,foo,*extras,food='spam'):
        pass
    def g(self,foo,*extras,**kwargs):
        pass
    def h(self,foo,*extras,food='spam',**kwargs):
        pass
    def i(self,*extras):
        pass
    def j(self,*extras,food='spam'):
        pass
    def k(self,*extras,**kwargs):
        pass
    def l(self,*extras,food='spam',**kwargs):
        pass
    def m(self,food='spam'):
        pass
    def n(self,food='spam',**kwargs):
        pass
    def o(self,**kwargs):
        pass


def dynamic_invoke(obj,name,parameters):
    action = getattr(obj,name)
    spec = inspect.getfullargspec(action)

    used = []
    args = ()
    kwargs = {}

    for a in spec.args[1:]:
        # skip the "self" argument since we are bound to a class
        args += (parameters[a], )
        used.append(a)

    if spec.varargs:
        args += tuple(parameters[spec.varargs])
        used.append(spec.varargs)

    for kw in spec.kwonlyargs:
        try:
            kwargs[kw] = parameters[kw]
            used.append(kw)
        except KeyError:
            pass

    # pass remaining parameters to kwargs, if allowed
    if spec.varkw:
        for k,v in parameters.items():
            if k not in used:
                kwargs[k] = v

    return action(*args,**kwargs)

me = MyClass()
params = {
        'foo':'bar',
        'extras':['one','two','three','four'],
        'food':'eggs',
        'parrot':'blue'
        }

dynamic_invoke(me,'a',params)
dynamic_invoke(me,'b',params)
dynamic_invoke(me,'c',params)
dynamic_invoke(me,'d',params)
dynamic_invoke(me,'e',params)
dynamic_invoke(me,'f',params)
dynamic_invoke(me,'g',params)
dynamic_invoke(me,'h',params)
dynamic_invoke(me,'i',params)
dynamic_invoke(me,'j',params)
dynamic_invoke(me,'k',params)
dynamic_invoke(me,'l',params)
dynamic_invoke(me,'m',params)
dynamic_invoke(me,'n',params)
dynamic_invoke(me,'o',params)
print('done!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
action = getattr(me,command['action'])
action(**{'a': 'Apple',
      'b': 'Banana',
      'args':['one','two','three','four'],
      'foo':'spam',
      'clowns':'bad',
      'chickens':'good'
     })
```